# Merge two array into array of jsonObjects

Tags: scala

I have two array.

```
A = ["apple", "mango", "banana"]
B = [true, false, true]
```

I want to merge this two like this,

```
C = [{ "apple" : true}, {"mango" : false}, {"banana" : true}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
val A = Array("apple", "mango", "banana")
val b = Array(true, false, true)

val C = a.zip(b).map(Map(_))
//=> Array(Map(apple -> true), Map(mango -> false), Map(banana -> true))
```

This gives you the Scala map array. If you need JSON, you can use your JSON library to serialize the `C` object to get the result.